# Trouble with japanese txt file and wordcloud output in python

Tags: python, utf-8, atom-editor, word-cloud

I referenced amueller's word cloud and a few others. It came to something like this:

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe
# coding: UTF-8
from os import path
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import MeCab as mc

d = path.dirname("C:\Users\BobLeponge\Desktop\jpn\JPNTEXT.txt")
text = open(path.join(d, 'JPNTEXT.txt')).read()
text = text.decode("utf-8")

def mecab_analysis(text):
    t = mc.Tagger('-Ochasen -d/usr/local/Cellar/mecab/0.996/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd/')
    enc_text = text.encode('utf-8')
    node = t.parseToNode(enc_text)
    output = []
    while(node):
        if node.surface != "":
            word_type = node.feature.split(",")[0]
            if word_type in ["形容詞", "動詞","名詞", "副詞"]:
                output.append(node.surface)
        node = node.next
        if node is None:
            break
    return output

def create_wordcloud(text):
    fpath = "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\NotoSansMonoCJKjp-Regular.otf"
    stop_words = [ u'てる', u'いる', u'なる', u'れる', u'する', u'ある', u'こと', u'これ', u'さん', u'して', \
         u'くれる', u'やる', u'くださる', u'そう', u'せる', u'した',  u'思う',  \
         u'それ', u'ここ', u'ちゃん', u'くん', u'', u'て',u'に',u'を',u'は',u'の', u'が', u'と', u'た', u'し', u'で', \
         u'ない', u'も', u'な', u'い', u'か', u'ので', u'よう', u'']
    wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color="white",font_path=fpath, width=900, height=500, \
                      stopwords=set(stop_words)).generate(text)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color="white", width=900, height=500).generate(text)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

When I execute it, this image pops up

[image]

I'm still a beginner at python so I'm not really sure what's wrong. I checked the encoding on the text file and it was utf-8, and `# coding: UTF-8` is at the beginning of the code so I assumed it would work. What am I doing wrong here?